# Java scrolled game issue

Tags: java, scroll

Hello I have a problem with my scrolled game. When scroll player is too fast for scrolling. I think the issue is not calculating coordinates displayed player.

Here is the code:

Main.class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
    Applet app;

    public static final int gameX = 660;
    public static final int gameY = 660;

    Thread thread;

    int map[][] = new int[29][52];

    boolean moveU = false;
    boolean moveD = false;
    boolean moveR = false;
    boolean moveL = false;

    loadImage loadImg = new loadImage();

    Player player;

    Graphics bgGrap;
    Image bgimage;

    public void init(){
        app = this;
        setSize(gameX, gameY);
        requestFocus();
        addKeyListener(this);

        loadMap();

        player = new Player(200,200);

        bgimage = createImage(gameX, gameY);
        bgGrap = bgimage.getGraphics();
    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        bgGrap.clearRect(0, 0, gameX, gameY);
        paint(bgGrap);
        g.drawImage(bgimage, 0, 0, app);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        drawHugeWorld(g);
        g.drawImage(loadImg.getImg("tree.PNG"), player.getX(), player.getY(), null); //here I draw the player.
    }
    public void start() {
        if(thread == null) 
        {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        if(thread != null)
        {
        thread = null;
        }
    }
    public void destroy(){
        thread = null;
    }
    public void drawHugeWorld(Graphics g){

        int cameraX = player.getX() - (gameX/2);
        int cameraY = player.getY() - (gameY/2);

        int tileX = cameraX/32;
        int tileY = cameraY/32;

        if(tileX % 32 != 0) {
                tileX--;
        }
        if(tileY % 32 != 0) {
                tileY--;
        }
        for (int y = tileY; y < cameraY + gameY; y+=32) 
        {
            for (int x = tileX; x < cameraX + gameX; x+=32)
            {
                switch(map[y/32][x/32])
                {
                case 0:
                    g.drawImage(loadImg.getImg("grass.png"), x - cameraX, y - cameraY, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    g.drawImage(loadImg.getImg("tree.png"), x - cameraX, y - cameraY, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void loadMap(){
        int map1[][] =
            {
                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
            };
        for(int j=0;j<map.length;j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<map[0].length;i++)
            {
            map[j][i] = map1[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while(thread != null){
            //System.out.println("ALIVE");
            if(moveU){
                player.addY(-1);
                repaint();
            }
            if(moveD){
                player.addY(1);
                repaint();
            }
            if(moveR){
                player.addX(1);
                repaint();
            }
            if(moveL){
                player.addX(-1);
                repaint();
            }
            try {
                thread.sleep(4);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            moveU = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            moveD = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            moveR = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            moveL = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            moveU = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            moveD = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            moveR = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            moveL = false;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
    }
}
```

And Player.class

```
public class Player {

    int x;
    int y;

    public Player(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void addX(int value){
        x += value;
    }
    public void addY(int value){
        y += value;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sleeping 4 milliseconds.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know :( If yes tell me. That sleep is for smooth movement. Only for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a pretty good first question, but I can't tell from your question what is actually wrong/being asked. Do you think you could clarify? Specifically, what behavior do you see, and what do you expect?

Comment: Player is too fast when scroll is stared player is too fast and he go behind the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you should change, it just came to me.

```
g.drawImage(loadImg.getImg("tree.PNG"), player.getX(), player.getY(), null); //here I draw the player.
```

You should not try changing the x, y position of the player perhaps if you are changing the camera.  For example, I tried hard-coding 200,200 instead of player.getX() and player.getY() and I got reasonable scrolling.  Maybe this is the effect you are after?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I solved the problem :). I only change this:                            g.drawImage(loadImg.getImg("tree.PNG"), player.getX() - cameraX, player.getY() - cameraY, null);